# how to add product to cart by url?

Tags: magento-1.9, url, addtocart

I need a add to cart URL for add the product to cart by open this URL in any browser.
I get the add to cart URL by this:

```
Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($simple_product)
```

output of above line is: :

```
http://192.168.0.78/pooja/testmagento/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovLzE5Mi4xNjguMC43OC9wb29qYS90ZXN0bWFnZW50by9pbmRleC5waHAvYWRtaW4vc3lzdGVtX2NvbmZpZy9lZGl0L3NlY3Rpb24vd2VvX3Byb2R1Y3RsaXN0L2tleS80YmI4NDEyZTg0ZWZjOTFhMmU1NWY4ZTkwNmIxOGY4OC8,/product/2/form_key/rnDRYdCccnTmYsRN/
```

When i hit the above URL, product is not add to cart. Empty cart page is appeared.

Any idea, how to solve it?

Comment: Above URL will not add product to cart. Because it will fail the  form key validation. 
so better way is to add a product with code instead of URL directly.

Comment: I need to use add to cart URL in custom module. any idea how to get the correct URL? @Magento2Learner

Comment: the above url should work as form key is added in the url itself, Magento it self uses the same code on product listing. Possible issue can be page content being cached and returning same form key everytime , You can try disable caching for the particular page

Comment: @Piyush is there any way to get the different form key for each product.

Comment: First check the url in different browsers, if you are getting exact same url in both browser then you can try to remove that particular page from cache using similar code in this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/167418/20064

Comment: @Piyush i get different URL on both browser.

Comment: This is not a recommended approach and will not work because other things like "form key" is not passed. The best way should be to call the rest API call "/rest/V1/carts/mine/items" OR "/rest/V1/guest-carts" to add an item into the basket. Don't hit the URL directly, that is not recommended approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change following;

setLocation

```
('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product)')
```

to

```
setLocation('<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product)')
```

or

remove the
 `onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"` in your phtml file.

Comment: ok i will try and let you know. @anikesh

Answer (score 0):

You need to check some magento files how they are generating the add to cart URL. 
Check

> app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php

File in that you will get one method `getAddToCartUrl()`
You may use this method to get add to cart URL.

Thanks.